# Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "f1"

Tags: pascal, freepascal

When creating a procedural data type, Free Pascal throws a strange error. But I'm passing one parameter, why is the number of parameters incorrect?

```
Type
    Func = Function (x:Real):Real;
    
Function middlfunc(a, b:Real; n:Integer; f:Func): Real;
Var
    x,s,d: Real; k:Integer;
Begin
    d:=(b-a)/n;
    s:=0;
    For k:=0 To n Do
    Begin
        x:=a+k*d;
        s:=s+f(x);
    End;
    middlfunc:=s/(n+1);
End;

Function f1(x:Real):Real; {There is the error}
Begin
    f1:=x*x;
End;

Var
    mf1:Real;
    a, b: real;
    n: integer;
    
Begin
    a := 0;
    b := 3.1415;
    n := 100;
    mf1 := middlfunc(a,b,n,f1); {ERROR :((((((((}
    WriteLn(mf1)
End.
```

Comment: I don't know Free Pascal, but almost certainly the compiler thinks you want to invoke `f1`, and since `f1` requires 1 argument and you pass 0, you get this error. Have you tried to write `middlfunc(a, b, n, @f1)`?

Comment: Or use {$mode delphi} or {$mode TP}

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  I expect I'm being obtuse, but why are you suggesting this when if would be simpler just to pass `f1` with the correct number of arguments, i.e. one?

Comment: @MartynA: The fourth argument of `middlfunc` is a `Func`, not a real number. So `f1` is OK, but `f1(something)` is not, because that is a number, not a function.

Comment: Good grief, so many bad answers. You must use `Addr(f1)` or `@f1` to pass the function pointer as argument to `middlfunc()`. See **Andreas Rejbrand**’s comments.

Answer (score -1):

> USE PASCAL **PROCEDURE** INSTEAD OF **FUNCTION**  for suitability

Comment: Procedures don’t return value. OP wants to use a _function_, which returns a value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a Function as a parameter to another function, then you have to do it like this:

```
Type
    TFunctionParameter = function(x: Real): Real;
    
Function middlfunc(a, b:Real; n:Integer; f:TFunctionParameter): Real;
Var
    x,s,d: Real; k:Integer;
Begin
    d:=(b-a)/n;
    s:=0;
    For k:=0 To n Do
    Begin
        x:=a+k*d;
        s:=s+f(x);
    End;
    middlfunc:=s/(n+1);
End;

function RaiseToSecondPower(x: Real): Real;
begin
  result := x*x;
end;

Var
    mf1:Real;
    a, b: real;
    n: integer;
Begin
    a := 0;
    b := 3.1415;
    n := 100;
    mf1 := middlfunc(a,b,n,RaiseToSecondPower);
    WriteLn(mf1)
End.
```